# How do I pre-select a SELECT element using the Angular 2 FormControl through binding

Tags: html, select, angular

We're using the Angular 2 FormControl and need to pre-select an HTML select element.

This was easy when we used ngModel because binding the control took care of the pre-selection. Here is the code we used before:

```
`<select 
    [(ngModel)]="ds.SerializedTimeZone"
    name="timezone"
    #dsTimeZone="ngModel">
<option *ngFor="let tz of timezones"
    [ngValue]="tz.Serialized">
    {{tz.DisplayName}}
</option>
</select>`
```

How can the same be accomplished when using the Angular 2 FormControl? 
I've tried setting selected as below but it doesn't work.
Here is the code using FormControl.

```
`<select name="timezone"
     formControlName="SerializedTimeZone"
     [(value)]="ds.SerializedTimeZone">
 <option *ngFor="let tz of timezones"
     [ngValue]="tz.Serialized"
     [selected]="tz.Serialized === ds.SerializedTimeZone">
     {{tz.DisplayName}}
 </option>
 </select>`
```

ds is an object with a property of SerializedTimeZone. 
timezones is a collection with two properties: Serialized and DisplayName

[selected]="" doesn't work in Angular 2 (stable 2.0)

Thanks!

Comment: Assign the object you want to have selected to `ds.SerializedTimeZone`, It needs to be the same instance not some other object with the same property values.

Comment: Thank you. Solved!